# SQL query to find Job ID and email name for triggered & scheduled email sends

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, sql, automationstudio, data-views

I was trying to implement this answer given in StackExchange - [Query for Emails sent in the past month, unsubscribes opens, clicks for each](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/184623/query-for-emails-sent-in-the-past-month-unsubscribes-opens-clicks-for-each)

If you look at, “III-C. SQL Query”, Paragraph in the answer, emails that were scheduled are picked up. But I want to implement this for all emails (even the ones sent through trigger)

Here is the code,

```
SELECT
    a.jobid
    ,a.emailname
    ,a.emailsubject
    ,a.schedtime
FROM _job a
WHERE DATEPART(m, a.schedtime) = DATEPART(m, DATEADD(m, -1, GETDATE()))
AND DATEPART(yyyy, a.schedtime) = DATEPART(yyyy, DATEADD(m, -1, GETDATE()))
```

What needs to be changed in the query to  include the triggered ones as well

Answer (score 1):

The Job data view picks up all email sends, so no need to adjust it for the use case you described:

> NOTE The Job data view provides results for all email send jobs in the
> Enterprise. The data view doesn’t categorize the results by send
> method.

Source: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_data_view_job.htm&type=5

If I am not mistaken, the `schedtime` in case of a triggered send would be showing the timestamp when the triggered send was published, so I would take those filters out to see all results.

Comment: @user0151 - if this answer helped you, please remember to accept it by clicking the checkmark - thanks!